# maven update pom property

Tags: maven, plugins

I'm looking for a way to update pom property to given value, i.e. my pom.xml contains:

```
<properties>
    <abc.def>aaaaa</abc.def>
<properties>
```

now i want to call :

```
mvn some_plugin:some_goal -Dabc.def=XYZ
```

and finally my pom.xml should looks like

```
<properties>
    <abc.def>XYZ</abc.def>
<properties>
```

I was reading about maven-release-plugin & versions-maven-plugin but i do not see there any matching goal.

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Comment: Are these properties for versions of dependencies?

Comment: Yes, they are. All i need to do is to update property in pom.xml and commit it to SVN by Jenkins invocation of maven command.

Comment: Than the versions-maven-plugin with the goal [update-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html) is the right choice.

Comment: khmarbaise, thank you for answer. As far as i checked (in documentation & simple example) update-properties goal of versions-maven-plugin 'Sets properties to the latest versions of specific artifacts' which is not always possible in my build and it updates <version> pom.xml, not particular property. If I'm missing something  please let me know :)

Comment: But you can give parameters on command line see the docs!

Comment: mvn versions:update-properties -Dproperties=[XYZ] -DincludeProperties={abc.def}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mvn versions:update-properties -Dproperties=[XYZ] -DincludeProperties={abc.def}`

Read more [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).
and [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html#properties).

In short:

In versions-maven-plugin, the `update-properties` goal sets properties to the latest versions of specific artifacts.

`includeProperties` is a comma separated list of properties to update.

`properties` are any restrictions that apply to specific properties.

Comment: I know that docu, but it does also not really explain it. The "-Dproperties" is actually of type Property (see: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html#properties) and therefore I don't understand what you try to do with "-Dproperties=[XYZ]". Your example is not working for me.

Comment: the XYZ in the question of @PawełDulęba is the new version he wants to set.

Comment: that did not work for me - it always tries to get the latest version, which might not be suitable. not all properties are for versions too. `sed -i "s|<abc.def>.*</abc.def>|\<abc.def>XYZ\</abc.def>|" pom.xml`

Comment: Downvoted because does not explain the command used and the link is dead.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer does not work for arbitrary values since it performs [sanity checks](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-property-mojo.html) (links to the documentation for `set-property` goal since for some reason the documentation for `update-properties` does not mention this).

To set some arbitrary value on a property use `set-property` since - as documented - it skips sanity checks:

```
mvn versions:set-property -Dproperty=your.property -DnewVersion=some_value
```

Comment: how to use it for multiple property with different version, i guess set-property works for only one new version

Answer (score 7):

Ok, i found some case of solution. I'm using maven-replacer-plugin where: 
my properties definition in pom.xml :

```
        <properties>
        <abc.def>aaaaa</abc.def>
    <properties>
```

my plugin configuration :

```
                <plugin>
           <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
           <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.2</version>
           <configuration>
               <file>pom.xml</file>
               <replacements>
                   <replacement>
                       <token>${abc.def}</token>
                       <value>${replacer.abc.def}</value>
                   </replacement>         
               </replacements>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and finally my maven invocation :

```
mvn replacer:replace -Dreplacer.abc.def=XYZ
```

It works for me but I don know is there any better way to achieve it with maven-relase-plugin and/or versions-maven-plugin as @khmarbaise and @Conan said.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @khmarbaise above, the versions-maven-plugin will do just this, or you could move to the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) if you want a much heftier approach to managing your versions, but you could also just run a script to sed the pom.xml file using Jenkins' `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable, which is a quicker and dirtier approach.

Comment: Conan, please check my answer to @khmarbaise about versions-maven-plugin. But i will try maven-release-plugin and it's goals.

Comment: The Maven Release Plugin will give you plenty of control over your versioning, but a word of warning - if you don't do everything in just the way the release plugin wants you to, it will bite you!