# Update Maven Dependency Properties With Pretty Snapshot Version

Tags: maven, properties, versioning, pom.xml, release

I currently have a maven release pipeline set up with multiple projects. I haven't been able to find a way to update dependency properties to the latest 'pretty' snapshot version after the `mvn release:perform`.

To clarify, here is the release pipeline:

`Release Project A --> Release Project B --> Release Project C...`

Project B pom.xml before release (pseudo pom):

```
<version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project-a.version>1.4.1-SNAPSHOT</project-a.version>
</properties>
```

During the release process, `<project-a.version>` is automatically updated to the latest release version, which in this case would be `1.4.1`.

After the release, project B's pseudo pom looks like this:

```
<version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project-a.version>1.4.1</project-a.version>
<properties>
```

For development and testing reasons, I would like the `<project-a.version>` to be set to `1.4.2-SNAPSHOT` after the release is performed, based on what the latest snapshot version is.

Using `mvn versions:update-properties -DallowSnapshots=true` kind of accomplishes this, but it leaves me with a very ugly snapshot version number and leaves me tied to a specific snapshot artifact:

```
<project-a.version>3b2a0d174a0658de1d3bfc777c248f83a8286e61-SNAPSHOT</project-a.version>
```

Is there anyway to get the general, 'pretty' version number? I'm assuming probably not, since the 'pretty' snapshot version number doesn't refer to one specific artifact, which is technically not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [maven update pom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739589/maven-update-pom-property). You can define the new value and specify which properties should be updated.
The links in the answer basically point to the Mojo desciption: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html

Comment: I stated in the question that I've already tried the maven `versions:update-properties` goal. But that gives me the long, artifact specific version. I don't want to have to manually set the version, I want the lookup to the repository to automatically use the most recent snapshot version.